# django "load comment"s not working correctly

Tags: python, web, django-comments

I am trying to implement a comment section on my app that keeps track of bookmarks.
This is the output that I got when I ran my local host server. It is not what I expected and I can't find out what's wrong. I expected there to be a comment form, a number for the comment count, and a comment list. But the webpage just rendered my code.
[image: This is the output that i got]
This is the code

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load comments %}
{% block title %}Bookmark:
{{ shared_bookmark.bookmark.title|escape }}{% endblock %}
{% block head %}


  <h2> Comments</h2>
  {% get_comment_count for bookmarks.sharedbookmark   
       shared_bookmark.id as comment_count %} 
  {% get_comment_list for bookmarks.sharedbookmark   
       shared_bookmark.id as comment_list %} 


   {% for comment in comment_list %}  
   <div class="comment">
             <p><b>{{ comment.user.username }}</b> said:</p>     
             {{ comment.comment|escape|urlizetrunc:40|linebreaks }}    
             </div> 
             {% endfor %}  
             <p>Number of comments: {{ comment_count }}</p> 
             {% comment_form for bookmarks.sharedbookmark    
             shared_bookmark.id %} 

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to show how you are rendering that template.

Comment: Can you include `base.html` here?

Comment: The Django comments framework is an optional module.  Have you enabled it in `settings.py`?

Comment: Also, why are you using `bookmarks.sharedbookmark shared_bookmark.id`?  Wouldn't it be more direct to just use `shared_bookmark`?

Comment: @JohnGordon yes here is my INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    #'django.contrib.comments',
    
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_comments',
    'hello',
    'comments',
    'bookmarks',
)

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm actually new to Django, so i'm just copying code that I found in a book here is the book: http://slav0nic.org.ua/static/books/python/Packt.Publishing.Learning.Website.Development.with.Django.Mar.2008.pdf

Comment: @VicktoryCalculusManOmole it looks like the comments module is commented out: `#'django.contrib.comments'`

Comment: @JohnGordon I had to comment out that one because it's deprecated and I had to use the new "django_comments"

Comment: I'm not sure that Django tags can be split on two lines like you have.  Try making one single long line for `{% get_comment_count ...`

Comment: My base.html<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>| {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href= "/site_media/style.css"
  type = "text/css" />
</head>
<body>
   
 
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    welcome {{ user.username }}
    (<a href="/logout">logout</a>)
  {% else %}
        
       
  {% endif %}
</div>
  <h1>{% block head %}{% endblock %}</h1>
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>

Comment: @VicktoryCalculusManOmole it's better to add information by editing your original question, instead of adding it in comments.

Comment: @JohnGordon Ok, thanks for the tip! I added everything to one line and I got "Invalid block tag on line 20: 'comment_form', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?". I am trying to look around online for any clues.

Comment: Did you mean to use `render_comment_form`?

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you so much everything works now! Thank you for being patient with me and helping me till the end.  A lot of people in this community wouldn't have done the same. Again, thank you so much; and have a good day :).